# Нужно ли в REST API выносить названия методов в отдельный файл с настройками?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Пишу rest api на spring. Контроллеры оборачиваю в @RequestMapping, а имена методов захардкодены. Например `@RequestMapping("register")`. Стоит ли их выносить в *.properties файл или есть более "спринговый" способ? Понимаю, что вопрос может показаться довольно глупым, просто хочу услышать мнение посторонних.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду xml конфигурацию?

Comment: моё мнение: писать названия эндпоинтов в @RequestMapping - не плохой способ. в нём нет ничего анти-спрингового. использовать аннотации для привязки методов обработки к эндпоинтам и есть "спринговый" способ.

Comment: @naXa вопрос в другом: стоит ли оставлять строки в `@RequestMapping` как есть или их нужно выносить в константы/файлы конфигураций?

Comment: @Jajavar мой ответ о том, что я не вижу необходимости выносить строки в константы / файлы конфигураций

Comment: @naXa просто везде учат, что нужно избегать таких случаев и все строки выносить в константы, мол, чтобы при изменениях не бегать по коду и не искать их. Вот я и думаю, а так ли часто меняются названия методов в веб сервисах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно создать такой класс:

```
public final class BaseApi {

    public static final String REGISTER = "/register";
    public static final String LOGIN = "/login";
    public static final String LOGOUT = "/logout";

    private BaseApi() {
        //prevents instantiation
    }
}
```

И потом при создании контроллера использовать статические импорты. Это нужно для того, чтобы ваши тесты и контроллеры использовали одинаковые константы. Если вы их захардкодите, то при изменении урл, вам понадобится менять и во всех остальных классах, а с таким подходом - только в одном классе.

Comment: я бы на всякий убрал ломбок, вряд ли автор с ним уже сталкивался и сейчас будет недоумевать, почему код не компилируется

Comment: @etki что такое ломбок?

Comment: @etki убрал, чтобы не путать.

Comment: @aleshka-batman и лучше тогда сделать интерфейсом, вместо класса.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor константный интерфейс считается анти-паттерном. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659593/what-is-the-use-of-interface-constants

Comment: @aleshka-batman антипаттерн только тогда и только тогда, когда имплиминтирует интерфейс какой-то класс для доступа к полям. но ведь можно не имплиминтировать и просто получить доступ через статик поле. ну ладно

Comment: @SeniorPomidor В том то  и дело, что невозможно запретить имплементить интерфейс.